# Cannot reinstall Windows after Ubuntu

Tags: boot, usb, windows, vaio, mbr

I recently installed Ubuntu on my laptop(Sony Vaio Duo 13). The laptop ONLY has two USB slots in the back, no disk drive. A bit later I realized that I still needed Windows for programs needed in University. I tried using rufus to make a bootable USB that had Windows 8.1 on it. I tested the USB on a friends laptop and it went right into the Windows installation. When I plug the USB into my computer it says that "My Sony could not read media(USB/CD)." I was a bit baffled by this so I made a bootable USB with Ubuntu on it. Ubuntu was able to start up in grub and gave me the option to install it. I reinstalled it to see if that was the case. It was not, I still could not boot to the USB with Windows on it. If I do not boot into Ubuntu, I get into the grub command line. I have also changed my BIOS setting around to each combination of possible differences, no help. I fear that I have deleted or corrupted something in my MBR. If anyone could help, that would be amazing, as I have not been able to fix this problem in days. Nothing on google, reddit or anywhere else has made any difference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to format your complete disk to NTFS format. Windows isn't very keen on anything else when it comes to installing it on your hard drive. With completely formatting it in NTFS (fx. with Gparted when in a Live CD session), you are also deleting GRUB. You should be able to boot into the Windows installer after that.

Comment: Just tried that, I still get the same error..